# Is hoisting inside a function done when the function is called or when it is compiled?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

In JavaScript, I am aware of how variable and function declarations are hoisted at the top of their respective scopes before executing the code.

Today, one question came to my mind regarding hoisting inside functions, for which I couldn't unfortunately find a good answer out there.

Consider the code below:

```
function f() {
    console.log(a);
    var a = 10;
}
```

The question is that: **is the `var` a declaration in the function `f` hoisted when `f` is compiled or when it is actually invoked?** And, whichever way is used, what's the reason behind using that?

Comment: It happens _before_ the step-by-step execution of the code and _hoisting_ just means that the javascript processes the declaration of variable `a` inside the function `f` before your code is executed. Variables and function declarations are not literally _moved_ to the top of the scope in which they are defined.

Comment: `f()` is not necessarily compiled at all, btw.

Comment: @tevemadar I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: @Yousaf so you mean that the `var a` declaration inside the function `f` would be hoisted when compiling `f` (when it is not yet invoked)?

Comment: Hoisting will happen _before_ any code is executed, so yes, it will happen before function `f` is invoked.

Comment: @Yousaf what about if `f` had another function `g` in it with exactly the same structure as `f`? Will hoisting *inside all* deeply nested functions happen when reading the code, **before actually executing it**?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Yousaf what disadvantages would there potentially be if hoisting variables inside a function was done at runtime, when executing the function?

Comment: That will delay the execution of the code because javascript engine will have to scan through each function before executing it.